# Simple Query Slow

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to get better performance out of this.

```
SELECT fdyofmth, SUM(total_restored) AS total_restored
FROM sum_restored
WHERE fdyofmth BETWEEN '2010-11-01' AND '2011-11-01'
GROUP BY fdyofmth
ORDER BY fdyofmth DESC
```

The result takes 3 secs.

```
+------------+----------------+
| fdyofmth   | total_restored |
+------------+----------------+
| 2011-11-01 |          39793 |
| 2011-10-01 |          52367 |
| 2011-09-01 |          52141 |
| 2011-08-01 |          56515 |
| 2011-07-01 |          54668 |
| 2011-06-01 |          54874 |
| 2011-05-01 |          60025 |
| 2011-04-01 |          60005 |
| 2011-03-01 |          63856 |
| 2011-02-01 |          64472 |
| 2011-01-01 |          58943 |
| 2010-12-01 |          57005 |
| 2010-11-01 |          55731 |
+------------+----------------+
```

EXPLAIN result -

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sum_restored | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 752660 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

I have tried putting a KEY of fdyofmth which actually made it twice as slow.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the types of the fields. Could you paste the CREATE? How many records do you have in that table? How slow is slow, could you paste the execution time.

Comment: An index on `fdyofmth` (by itself) would help.  Is there one?

Comment: @NedretRecep I am not at work now so I can not paste the CREATE but the fields are "DATE - fdyofmth" and "INT - total_restored". As I said it takes 3 secs to show the results and with an index on the fdyofmth it takes 6 secs - total rows in this table is 752K as per explain plan. thanks.

Comment: are  the dates in the where clause random according to your business logic of the app? if not, one direction to optimize is in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is slow, because you have so much data, and your sql has to go through all the data(**not pick one from the whole data set**), so `index` can not help here.

The option i propose is use parallelism:

> 1. add the index as suggested by @newtover
> 2. use 12 threads to retrieve the results for each month.

Or even simpler:

> just pre-compute the result into another table, 
>   when query, query from that table.

Comment: I like the idea of pre-computing the value and storing in another table but the problem is that those dates are random based on user selection. Also they can apply filters to other columns in the table which will also affect the results, so I dont think its going to be possible? What amazes me is that the same query against an ORACLE DB is about 500ms :-/ weird or what?

Comment: there are some settings you can tune, for example, if you are using **innodb** the most important setting might be `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, mostly you should allocate  most of your memory to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
If the dates are not the same, then

```
SELECT fdyofmth, SUM(total_restored) AS total_restored
FROM sum_restored
WHERE fdyofmth >= '2010-11-01' AND fdyofmth <= '2011-12-01'
GROUP BY fdyofmth
ORDER BY fdyofmth DESC
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the response I have tried that and it was pretty much the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

According to your `EXPLAIN` results, the query doesn't use any indexes. You need to set up an index on `fdyofmth`:

```
ALTER TABLE sum_restored ADD INDEX fdyofmth_index (fdyofmth);
```

Or another suggestion =):

```
SELECT
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2010-11-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2010-11-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2010-12-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2010-12-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-01-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-01-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-02-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-02-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-03-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-03-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-04-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-04-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-05-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-05-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-06-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-06-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-07-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-07-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-08-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-08-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-09-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-09-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-10-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-10-01`,
    SUM (IF(fdyofmth = '2011-11-01', total_restored, NULL)) as `2011-11-01`
FROM sum_restored;
```

Comment: will it be faster? the query has go through all the data anyway, even if you have the index.

Comment: @newtover as I explained in my question I did put an index on fdyofmth but doing so took the query from 3 secs to 6 secs which baffled me :(

Comment: @james-xu, the field is used in the `WHERE` condition, an it might help, if it cut a significant part by one of the comparisons in `BETWEEN`. But you seem to be right: the condition is very broad and too much data.

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve this outside query changes.

- Create another table to hold the ready calculated summaries for each past month
- cut down the size of the table a lot. Another table for every year or every month or row changes.